# NavigationService WithParam of Caliburn Micro for WP

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, caliburn.micro

As is well known, CM doesn't support passing a object of complex type through NavigationService like MVVM Light. So I searched for a workaround and did it like this.

There are two viewmodels: MainPageViewModel and SubPageViewModel.

I first defined 3 classes, namely GlobalData, SnapshotCache and StockSnapshot. StockSnapshot is the type of which the object I want to pass between the 2 viewmodels.

```
public class SnapshotCache : Dictionary<string, StockSnapshot>
{
    public StockSnapshot GetFromCache(string key)
    {
        if (ContainsKey(key))
            return this[key];

        return null;
    }
}

public class GlobalData
{
    private GlobalData()
    {

    }

    private static GlobalData _current;
    public static GlobalData Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (_current == null)
                _current = new GlobalData();

            return _current;
        }
        set { _current = value; }
    }

    private SnapshotCache _cachedStops;
    public SnapshotCache Snapshots
    {
        get
        {
            if (_cachedStops == null)
                _cachedStops = new SnapshotCache();

            return _cachedStops;
        }
    }
}

public class StockSnapshot
{
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Next, I call the navigation service on MainPageViewModel like this:

```
StockSnapshot snap = new StockSnapshot {Symbol="1", Message = "The SampleText is here again!" };
GlobalData.Current.Snapshots[snap.Symbol] = snap;
NavigationService.UriFor<SubPageViewModel>().WithParam(p=>p.Symbol,snap.Symbol).Navigate();
```

And on SubPageViewModel I've got this:

```
    private string _symbol;
    public string Symbol
    {
        get { return _symbol; }
        set
        {
            _symbol = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Symbol);
        }
    }

    public StockSnapshot Snapshot
    {
        get { return GlobalData.Current.Snapshots[Symbol]; }
    }
```

And that's where the problem lies. When I run the program, I find out that it always runs to the getter of Snapshot first, when Symbol hasn't been initialized yet. So later I've tried adding some extra code to eliminate the ArgumentNullException so that it can run to the setter of Symbol and then everything goes fine except that the UI doesn't get updated anyway.

Could anyone tell me where I've got wrong?
Thx in advance!!

Comment: Why don't you just register GlobalData as a singleton and inject it into the ViewModel's that need it?

Comment: I've tried that only to get a weird MissingMethodException on GetInstance() of BootStrapper without knowing what's wrong. Here's [a link which describes exactly the same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914090/missingmethodexception-caliburn).

Comment: Odd, I do this a lot and haven't run into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use:

```
private string _symbol;     
public string Symbol     
{         
    get { return _symbol;}         

    set         
    {             
        _symbol = value;            
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Symbol);   
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Snapshot);        
    }     
}      
public StockSnapshot Snapshot     
{         
    get { return Symbol!=null? GlobalData.Current.Snapshots[Symbol]:null; }     
}
```

In this case you don't try and get the data from GlobalData when Symbol is null (sensible approach anyway!) and when "Symbol" is set you call NotifyOfPropertyChange() on Snapshot to force a re-get of the property.

Comment: It seems to be a workaround. Anyway, that works fine for me. And it turned out an issue with the last version of Caliburn Micro. After I got it updated to the latest, things went smoothly. :)